# How to use Joystick Emulator in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, joystick

I'm developing the WebGL game need to be controlled by a joystick.
But I don't have a joystick device.
I don't have any idea which joystick emulator is the best for unity and how to use it.

Comment: Use an on-screen joystick ui that is enough emulated compare to a real one.

Comment: i don't know about on-scree joystick ui.

Comment: You can use this for example https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631
or may be use the built in on-screen joystick provided with unity's new input system. See some videos on youtube for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe connect a playstation/xbox controller via a usb cable to your computer. Then you could it to see if your controller works on your computer by using this website: [https://gamepad-tester.com](https://gamepad-tester.com/)

then look at this to see if it works, the different parts of the controller in the image should react to what you do with the controller in real life: [image]